# Why is my test changing the length of a byte array?

Tags: rust

I have the following test:

```
pub(crate) fn from_byte_slice(packet: &[u8]) -> BackendKeyData {
    let mut backend = BackendKeyData::new();

    backend.pid = i32::from_be_bytes(pop(&packet[5..9]));
    backend.key = i32::from_be_bytes(pop(&packet[9..]));

    backend
}

#[test]
fn test_backend_key_data() {
    let bytes = b"\x75\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x149\x241\x17\x173\x241\x137";
    let backend = BackendKeyData::from_byte_slice(bytes);
    assert_eq!(backend.pid, 0);
}
```

When I debug the test the byte array changes and becomes this slice:

```
[0]:117
[1]:0
[2]:0
[3]:0
[4]:18
[5]:0
[6]:0
[7]:20
[8]:57
[9]:36
[10]:49
[11]:23
[12]:23
[13]:51
[14]:36
[15]:49
[16]:19
[17]:55
```

What's going on here, why the change?

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting, but `\x137` is `\x13` (the byte with value `0x13` or `19`) followed by the ascii character `7` (the byte with value `0x37` or `55`).

Comment: Anything over 0xFF results in a high and low byte - 3 hex digits = 2 bytes instead of one. At first glance, your results look about right to me.

Comment: It seems like you're supplying base 10 numbers, so you're probably looking for `&[75, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 149, 241, 17, 173, 241, 137]`

Comment: @Aplet123 want to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\x` is for 2 digit hexadecimal escapes only. `\x137` does not make a byte with value 137, but instead a byte with value `0x13` followed by the byte represented by the ascii character `7`. Use an array literal for base 10 values instead:

```rust
&[75, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 149, 241, 17, 173, 241, 137]
```